# Customize single option selector in Shopify theme

Tags: drop-down-menu, shopify, styling

I have a single option selector displaying my product variants in a drop down list.

[image]

I want to display my options in a button style instead of a drop down list?

[image]

What is the name of the button-style list and how to do it in Shopify's Venture theme?

Comment: I think you need to check the theme customizer for product swatch, I think there is by default this type of code add-in Shopify most of paid themes or even into free themes also.

Comment: Venture does not provide a button option style on the product page, you can customize your ```product.liquid``` file

Comment: @Zain thanks for your reply, do you recommend any tutorials to help me do that

Comment: @A_Matar, I hope you will get something from this https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Design/Product-pages-Add-color-swatches-to-products/m-p/616427